# Adding ellipses to placeholder in textinput in react native

Tags: react-native, overflow, textinput

I am trying to add ellipses to the end of the placeholder in my textinput in react native. I am actually using Google Maps API to get the location and display the current location as a placeholder of my text input. This is what is happening:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/53R8I.png

How can I display the placeholder in one line, moreover add ellipses to it.

Answer (score 1):

When you get the location from API, just get extract 40 to 50 characters from the starts of the location string like

```
const userLocation = "C-5, Gilbertg Green Block C Gilbertg Green . . .";
var placeholder = userLocation.slice(0, 40);
```

Comment: Isn't there a more generic method? Some way that the text input handles it by itself?

Comment: I was tried once but couldn't get any other way of doing this.